# xaml style - how to make colors change on key

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, dynamicresource

I have the brushes with different colors below.

```xml
<!-- SolidColorBrush -->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="#FFDDDDDD"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFBEE6FD"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF3C7FB1"/>
```

That I want to change to be red, for a negative button. I.e. not static, but switching them. Not at runtime, (at first) based on some value..

fx: int I = 0;

```xml
<!-- SolidColorBrush -->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="Red"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="DarkRed/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="LightRed"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#Red"/>
```

I == 1

```xml
<!-- SolidColorBrush -->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="Yellow"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="DarkYellow"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="LightYellow"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#Yellow"/>
```

I == 2

```xml
<!-- SolidColorBrush -->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="Green"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="DarkGreen"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="LightGreen"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#Green"/>
```

There must be some smart way to set the default colors and not just being limited to one style of button... so I can bind the differnt colors used in the xaml to make different styles of buttons..

Anyone have an idea, feel free to make a comment..

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the resource dynamically:

```
Resources["Button.Static.Background"] = Brushes.Yellow;
```

For this to affect any element that currently references this resource, you need to reference it using the `DynamicResource` markup extension:

```
<TextBlock Text="Test" Foreground="{DynamicResource Button.Static.Background}" />
```

The default `Button` template does not use `DynamicResource` so you cannot change the colours of a button without modifying the template by for example replacing `StaticResource` with `DynamicResource`.

Comment: I am thinking, what I really would love, was to have use a key, with a directory of colors. 
i.e. red, green,yellow. and then chaning with the groups of colors..

Comment: You could put all related resources in a `ResourceDictonary` and then replace this one with another one to change colours.

Comment: That is exactly what I did, and the right way to do it (I think)

Comment: @kfn: So what's your remaining question?